# How to prevent sending more than one request while waiting ajax to execute?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I do have an anchor which, when pressed is sending an ajax request to swap element and while waiting it to execute i can click it one more time and send another request. How to prevent this situation?

```rb
<% if current_or_guest_user.follow?(id_to_follow) %>
  <%= link_to raw('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close"></span> Unfollow'), unfollow_path(follow.id), method: "delete", remote: true,
              class: 'btn btn-warning follow-link', id: 'unfollow'%>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to raw('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Follow'), follow_path(following_id: id_to_follow), method: "post", remote: true,
              class: 'btn btn-success follow-link', id: 'follow' %>
<% end %>
```

```
 $(document).on('ajax:success',"#unfollow", function(xhr, data){
        $(this).replaceWith(data['follow']);
    });

    $(document).on('ajax:success', "#follow", function(xhr, data){
        $(this).replaceWith(data['follow']);
    });
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [Automatic disabling](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#automatic-disabling) section of the guide?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't find it before, now it works thanks :)